Mutually Correlated Events
Given random events $A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n$, consider the two properties:
(1) For all $I\subseteq[n]$, $\ \ \mathbb P\Big[\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\Big]\leq \prod_{i\in I}\mathbb P[A_i]$
(2) For all $I\subseteq[n]$ and $k\notin I$, $\ \ \mathbb P\Big[A_k\big|\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\Big]\leq \mathbb P[A_k]$
Clearly $(2)\!\!\!\implies\!\!\!(1)$, but showing $(1)\not\!\!\!\implies\!\!\!(2)$ is a nice puzzle.

Let $X\sim\text{Unif}\{0,1,\ldots, 99\}$. For $i\in \{0,1,2\}$, let $A_i=\big(X=0\vee X\equiv i\pmod 3\big)$. Then (1) holds but (2) fails.

Both of these seem like generalizations of "negatively correlated events," but do they each have a definition? I know (1) suffices to get Chernoff bounds but obviously (2) is stronger. Can someone share definitions/sources for these?

It is related to the concepts of positive quadrant dependence and negative quadrant dependence, broadly used in multivariate analysis.

What is that tent symbol?

@Amir After some googling, I'm unable to see how these concepts relate to my question. Could provide a source? To be clear, I'm asking about the names for two different properties.

@Michael the \wedge means "and," alternately denoted with a \cap.

In terms of standard definitions it would be typical to use the intersection symbol (indeed having latex \cap) rather than a logical “and.” That is because events are formally defined as sets, rather than logical propositions, so that intersection is appropriate. The “and” only makes sense in the intuitive interpretation that “two events both are true” (of course a set cannot be true or false). The intuition makes sense in a thought experiment with a “random” outcome $\omega$ and we  imagine an event $A$ is “true” if $\omega \in A$.

@Michael I know this (I actually use \cap in my own work, but I see \wedge more often on SE). Please restrict your response to the content of the question rather than the notation.
